# PyQt5 DoubleSpinBox in QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Using PyQt5 setting up an editor delegate as a QDoubleSpinBox:

```
class MoneyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(MoneyDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        val = float(index.data())
        option.text = '${:,.2f}'.format(val)
        option.displayAlignment = Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight

    def createEditor(self, QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex):
        super(MoneyDelegate, self).createEditor(QWidget, QStyleOptionViewItem, QModelIndex)
        editor = QDoubleSpinBox(self)
        editor.setMinimum(.01)
        editor.setMaximum(999999.99)
        return(editor)
```

In my QTableWidget class:

```
self.tbl_View.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, MoneyDelegate(self))
```

Problem I am having is that the editor shows up in the upper left corner of the screen as a separate dialog.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `QWidget`, `QStyleOptionViewItem` and `QModelIndex` as the name of the parameters of a function since they are the name of the classes and you are obfuscating them. On the other hand you must pass as the parent of the editor to the first parameter of [`createEditor()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html#createEditor):

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    editor = QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
    editor.setMinimum(.01)
    editor.setMaximum(999999.99)
    return editor
```

Comment: Should have known better. Thanks Eyllanesc!